# Marklogic server version downgrade?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I currently have Marklogic server version 9.0-12 installed and running. A project I am working on requires me to have version 9.0-8 installed, as the data hub version is incompatible with the current version I have.  Is there a way I can downgrade to this version? I can not seem to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic does not support downgrades.  There are changes made to the underlying files that break it working with the older version.

Your best bet is to backup the content databases, and restore them to the version that you need.

https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/34/0/marklogic-server-version-downgrades-are-not-supported